# private variables in java?

Tags: java

I was watching a tutorial on youtube and the topic was private variables. We usually set variables in java like this:

```
class hello {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String x;
        x = "Hello"
    }
}
```

but in that tutorial, the string type was declared out of the method like this:

```
class hello {

    private String x;

    public void apples() {
        x = "this is a private variable.";
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

As you can see it was not the main method, but i want to ask that do private variables always have to be out of method or what?

I am a beginner so this will be really helpful to know as i don't want to cram up knowledge to prevent confusion and also because it is a matter of fact that people who cram up code never become a good programmer.

Comment: @chronodekar You can defintely define global variables in C, which are not inside of functions/methods. I think you need to refresh yourself on this.

Comment: My apologies. Zéychin is correct. I think *I* was the one getting confused with languages here. :(  (older comment now deleted due to inaccuracy)

Answer (score 4):

> ***do private variables always have to be out of method or what?***

That's right. A variable inside a method is a **local variable** and can not have any access modifiers such as private, public or protected. These modifiers can only be applied to **member variables**, i.e. variables that are declared in the class scope.

If you think about it, it makes a lot of sense, since local variables can't be accessed by another class anyway. Not even another object of the same class or another method in the same object.

**Related question:**

- [What is the difference between a member variable and a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177723/what-is-the-difference-between-a-member-variable-and-a-local-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Cass variables must be declared to be one of the following types:

Public

Protected

Public

In the first example, the variable is local to the function: that is, it's specifically bound to method hello.main().

In that case, it's only accessible within that method function. It's not a class variable, so it doesn't need its access level to be set.

In the second example, the variable is a class variable. When you have a class variable, you can set it to private (can only be accessed by an object of that class), protected (accessed by inherited classes), or public (can be accessed outside of the object). The many methods possible inside the class can then access that class variable.

When you have a variable set inside a class definition, and not inside a method, it is called a "field" or "property" or "attribute." The way you define the accessibility of the field is required since multiple methods within the class can refer to it.

When you have a variable set within any method, it can only be accessed inside of that method, and can't be accessed outside (unless you use a reference pointer or pass it through method arguments).

Answer (score 0):

A **private** variable in Java is a variable Globally accessible to the class and only to that class (and of course any other methods in the containing class).

A variable declared within a method can be accessed only within the scope of the method. A variable declared inside an if statement is only accessible inside the if statement .... and so on.

Its best to have as little **private** variable as possible because of performance issues. Lets say you have 100 private variables declared in a class. Your class contains 10 methods and each method utilizes 10 variables. When instantiating an object then your object is created instantiating olso the 100 private variables. If you make you variables local to your methods, then no variable is created on instantiation of the class, and 10 variables are used each time you access a method....

There are also other types of variables in java, to better comprehend you can start from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what's confusing you is the distinction between a local variable (declared in a method), and a member variable (declared in a class, outside of the class's methods).

A local variable exists just while the method that it's declared in is running.  It comes into existence at the point that it's declared, then goes out of scope later, when the next } character occurs (other than those that match { characters that aren't opened yet).  This effectively means that the variable disappears in a puff of smoke - it can't be used once it's gone out of scope.

But a member variable lives inside an object.  That means it gets created when the object is created, and destroyed when the object is destroyed.  So it typically lives for a much longer duration than the local variables do.  Member variables can sometimes be used by objects other than the object that they belong to; and there are some quite complex rules around when it's possible to do this.

The `private` modifier on a member variable just means that it can only be accessed by code that's in the class that the object belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

```
 but i want to ask that do private variables always have to be out of method or what?.
```

Well, It doesn't make sense actually to make a variable private in a method. **Because variables  declared in a method are stack variables and they have narrower scope than a private one**. As they can be accessed only in the method they are declared in and private variables have scope in the whole class they are declared in.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable created with in a scope ( code block bounded inside { } ) is a `local` variable of that scope; and not accessible out side the block.

Also `private` variables is term which comes into picture when you talk about classes and define a member which is not accessible **outside** class.