# How would I reference a variable obtained from a private function in another function?

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I'm hoping someone can help me. I am relatively new and would like to understand how to pass the value of the variable in one class to another. In this case I would like to use numPage and filePath array from Button_Click_1 in Button_Click_2.

Thank you in advance!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (.jpg)|*.jpg";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            string[] filePaths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            int imageNum = 0;
            lblFilePath.Content = filePaths[imageNum];
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imageNum++;
        lblFilePath.Content = filePath[imageNum];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something every C# developer if not most should know here is a MSDN site that will help you in understanding `Access Modifiers` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: Another useful link - [What is the difference between a member variable and a local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177723/what-is-the-difference-between-a-member-variable-and-a-local-variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just need to store them as class instance variables instead of local method variables.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // These can now be accessed from any method in this class.
    private string[] filepaths = null;
    private int imageNum = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (.jpg)|*.jpg";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            // You can use the keyword "this" to access instance variables, but it is optional.
            this.filePaths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            this.imageNum = 0;
            lblFilePath.Content = this.filePaths[this.imageNum];
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // You may want to put some validation in here to prevent errors situations.

        // Validate that filePaths has been initialized.
        if (this.filePaths == null)
        {
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No files paths to display.");
        }
        // Validate that imageNum can be incremented without IndexOutOfRangeException.
        else if (this.imageNum < this.filePaths.Length - 1)
        {
            this.imageNum++;
            lblFilePath.Content = this.filePaths[this.imageNum];
        }
        // Otherwise, loop back to the first file path.
        else
        {
            this.imageNum = 0;
            lblFilePath.Content = this.filePaths[this.imageNum];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) in class MainWindow.

```
private string[] FilePaths{get;set;}
```

Replace variable filePath with FilePath.

Comment: You need to also be careful with filePaths that if Button2 is clicked before Button1 (if that is possible) then you will get an error trying to access it. Even if it is initialised if imageNum is higher than the upper bound of filePaths then you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance variables here, rather than scoping the variables to be local to the method:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string[] filePaths;
    private int imageNum = 0;

    //...

}
```

Then you can use those instance variables (make sure to not re-define new local variables with the same name) in the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

make both as properties of form 1

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   private string[] FilePaths {get;set;}
   int imageNum = 0;

   public MainWindow()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
   }

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Images (.jpg)|*.jpg";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

    bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (userClickedOK == true)
    {
        FilePaths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

        lblFilePath.Content = filePaths[imageNum];
    }

}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    imageNum++;
     if(imageNum<FilePaths.Length)
         lblFilePath.Content = FilePaths[imageNum];
}
```

}