# Difference between Class variable, Member variable, and Local variable, Global Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Categorize between `Class variable, Member variable, Local variable and Global Variable?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177723/what-is-the-difference-between-a-member-variable-and-a-local-variable) should be a good explanation.

Comment: Locals are declared inside blocks, like a method block or a `for` block and the lifetime of them are defined by the curly brackets { } in which they are contained. The link above is a good explanation but doesn't really go into what defines "local".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a variable defined static in class definition is class variable.

```
public MyClass
{
    static int a; // class variable
}
```

a variable declared in a function (Method) is local variable.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string name; //local variable
    }
}
```

a variable declared in a class definition, and when class is instantiated and those variables will be member variable

```
public class MyClass
{
    int a; // here they are local variable of class body.
    int b;
}

//create instance of class

MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.a = 10; //these are member variables
mc.b = 11;
```

Comment: As far as member variables go, i don't think mc.a will be available outside of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Going a little further than the linked question in the comments about "local" variables...

A "local" variable is a variable which the lifetime is defined by the curly brackets in which it is contained. For example:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    int a = 0;    //a is a local variable that is alive from this point down to }
}
```

But there are other types of local variables, for example:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int a = 0;
        //a and i are local inside this for loop
    }
    //i and a do not exist here
}
```

Or even something like this is valid (but not recommended):

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    int x = 0;
    {
         int a = 0;
         //a exists inside here, until the next }
         //x also exists in here because its defined in a parent scope
    }
    //a does not exist here, but x does
}
```

The `{` and `}` are scoping delimiters. They define a scope of something. When defined under a method, they define the scope for the code that belongs to the method. They also define the scope of things like `for`, `if`, `switch`, `class`, etc. They define a **local** scope.

For completeness, here is a class/member variable:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeVariable;
}
```

Here, `SomeVariable` is defined in the `SomeClass` scope, and can be accessed through instances of the `SomeClass` class:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.SomeVariable = 10;
```

People call `static` variables class variables but I don't agree with the definition, static classes are like singleton instances and I like to think of them as member variables.

Its also highly recommended that you use properties instead of public mutable members when exposing data outside a class.