# Stack in C# Form, proceed button for Push

Tags: c#, stack

I'm having trouble implementing stack and query into C# Form application.

My code looks like this.

```
namespace Program_Pajak
{
    public partial class formppn : Form
    {
        public formppn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void formppn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//kinda confused, placing stack in which function
        {
            Stack sit = new Stack();
            Stack sht = new Stack();
            int count1 = sit.Count;
            int count2 = sht.Count;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is proceed button for Push stack
        {
            sit.Push(item);
            si.Text = count1.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know which function should I declare my stack, and how to make proceed button to push data onto my stack?

Comment: make `sit` and `sht` [member variables rather than local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725415/difference-between-class-variable-member-variable-and-local-variable-global-v)

Comment: @orhtej2, would you care to post your suggestion as answer? I will remove mine, and up-vote yours :-)

Comment: @ironstone13 no need, I upvoted your answer as it (IMO) answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @orhtej2 pointed out in his comment, you should declare your data as member variables of the `formpn` class. You would also be better off using a typed [generic version of stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) and using [readonly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) declaration to make it clear you're not going to re-assign the collections later:

```
  namespace Program_Pajak
    {
        public partial class formppn : Form
        {

           Stack sit = new Stack();
           Stack sht = new Stack();

            public formppn()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void formppn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//kinda confused, placing stack in which function
            {

                int count1 = sit.Count;
                int count2 = sht.Count;
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //this is proceed button for Push stack
            {
                sit.Push(item);
                si.Text = count1.ToString();
            }

            private void si_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @yogagrmy99, please mark as answer if it worked :-)
Thanks!