# C# Confusion About List Instances and Context of Members

Tags: c#, list

I am confused as to why this works:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
   public class NameList
    {
        public void NameListGo()
        {
            List<string> listofNames = new List<string>();
            listofNames.Add("Frank");
        }
    }
}
```

But this produces an error where "listofNames" cannot be found in the current context:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
   public class NameList
    {
            List<string> listofNames = new List<string>();
            listofNames.Add("Frank");
    }
}
```

What is the role of the method "NameListGo" in this situation. Must an instance be contained within a method in order to reference said instance's properties? (I started learning C# over the long weekend so sorry if this is rookie question).

Comment: in the second one, u need to put yr code in either constructor or a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

### Bottom line

This is because `listofNames.Add("Frank");` is an instruction and as you can see in [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods):

> In C#, every executed instruction is performed in the context of a method.

---

### How to make it work

In the 1st snippet `listOfNames` is a local variable.

In the 2nd snippet `listOfNames` as a member variable.

More precisely in the 2nd snippet `listofNames` is a field of the `NameList` class.

```
public class NameList
{
       //This is a field
        List<string> listofNames = new List<string>();

       public void Method() {
          //You need a method to interact with listOfNames
          listofNames.Add("Frank");
       }

}
```

Please check out [What is the difference between a member variable and a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177723/what-is-the-difference-between-a-member-variable-and-a-local-variable)

### Summary

I recommend more tutorials - it will become clear over time. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is super clear and makes a lot of sense.