# Why can't I use data created in my constructor in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, database, constructor, windows-forms-designer, windows-forms-core

I am trying to create a Desktop Application that is basically a pet orphanage for people to donate and receive pets without home. I created my database and my design for the app, but my progress is blocked by the fact that whatever variables, parameters or anything I create inside the public : Form2 ( ) constructor cannot be used inside the rest of the code. I have multiple tutorials that I follow for the moment in order to create my application, and all of the use the same approach ( Create database connection inside the constructor of the form, where InitializeComponents() is located, then use that same connection throughout the code ).

I seem to encounter an issue that basically stops me from using anything created inside the constructor ( image below ).
[image]

This is stopping me not only with the connection. For example if I create an instance of an User Control like this:

ucHome home1 = new ucHome();
home1.BringToFront();

Everything is working fine and the UC is brought to front but if somewhere in the code ( anywhere ) like a Button-Click function I try to use the method home1.SendToBack() for example the code will not recognize home1 and will tell me it is undeclared.

Any ideas of how I might fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, please don't post pictures of code, post the actual text here. Secondly, you have defined the variable `databaseConnection` inside the constructor so that is where is is scoped to.

Comment: [What is the difference between a member variable and a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1177723)

Comment: Don't cache conection objects. Just create them when you need them, and dispose iwth `using`. See [C# Data Connections Best Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552829/c-sharp-data-connections-best-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the sql context at GetData method because actually your context scope is only the constructor.

Try this

```
private void GetData(MySQLConnection sqlConnection)
{
// Data find
}
```

Do not forget call GetData method on form2 constructor.

Comment: I tried doing this but I receive : "Connection must be valid or open SQL" error.

Comment: sqlConnection is initialized correctly? Is the connection string populated? Is the connection open?

Comment: Try add sqlConnection.Open() before query and sqlConnection.Close() / dispose after process.